# CSS3 add cursor transitions

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to add a css3 transition to a cursor image which in the body tag without animate the whole body ...

perhaps adding the class somewhere?

```
.cursor { cursor: url("/images/light1_CROP.png"), auto;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 4.1s;
}
[...]
```

won't work ...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. First what do you mean by "without animating the whole body"? Second, from your code it looks like you have a div `.cursor` that you're animating and want to change the cursor image when you're hovering that div. But your description implies that you actually want to animate the cursor image itself. Can you please clarify and add some html code if applicable or maybe a fiddle?

Comment: not on hover on a div, i want to animate only cursor inside the body but i still animate the whole body when i add the class to body, simply animate the cursor itself without using a gif ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out before: You can not animate the cursor property. Additionally the way you tried to do it can't work because you're animation some div on your page but not the cursor itself.

Here's what you can do:
You can hide the regular cursor, put your cursor-image inside a div (in my example, I choose to do that as a background-image) and move it together with the cursor using javascript.

Now you can animate your cursor-div however you like.

```js
$(document).mouseenter(function() {
  $('.cursor').show();
});
$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.cursor').hide();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var posX = e.pageX - 19,
    posY = e.pageY - 21;
  $('.cursor').css({
      left: posX + 'px',
      top: posY + 'px'
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  background-image: url("http://stormfall.linuxweb.net/images/light1_CROP.png");
  width: 39px;
  height: 42px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 4.1s;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: -21px;
  left: -19px;
}

body {
  cursor: none;
}

@keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Move your mouse here...
<div class="cursor">
</div>
```

However there is one drawback: This works as long as you don't want to click on anything because the cursor-div will be in the way of every click, so if you have some clickable elements on your page like links or buttons, you have to figure out a way to redirect all click-events from your cursor-div to whatever is underneath it.

Comment: Exactly what i need, THANK YOU, why I didn't think of it  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to animate image given in css cursor property.
But you can do it using javascript by changing image every interval.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)